# volkswagen passat 2002

Tags: electrical, vw, passat

I have a passat and the previous owner fitted a DEFA alarm system which is pretty useless.  It appears to interfere with the central locking and wing mirror electric control.  I have removed it and are now left with the factory plugs but they have nowhere to go.  Does anyone know what the plugs from the door plug into?  There seems to be a space for fuse 30 but its not present.  The electric windows work so there is some power to the door.

Not too worried about central locking but electric wing mirrors I need to get it through its annual test.

Help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!